# Change styling of a PrimeNG Tree

Tags: html, sass, primeng

I have a p-PrimeNG sidebar, which includes a fieldset, which itself includes a tree:

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display" position="right">
    <h2>My Checklist</h2>    
    <fieldset class="default-fieldset">
      <legend>Legend ...</legend>
      <p-tree [value]="filesTree2"></p-tree>
    </fieldset>        
</p-sidebar>
```

I need to be able to remove the border around the tree, as fieldset has already a border. I tried the following codes inside the scss file:

- `fieldset p-tree { border: none;}`
- `fieldset p-tree { border: transparent;}`

but none of them has been helpful.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: which version of primeNG are you using?

Comment: @jituthakur I use PrimeNG 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS:

```
p-sidebar .ui-tree{
  border: none;
}
```

because p-tree compiled and created an HTML with "UI-tree" so you apply all CSS in this class.

Comment: write  "!important" in last of ".border: none !important".

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.
Could you please give a plunker link to your working code?

Comment: you can the live URL then I can tell you what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply your css selectors in styles.scss, in order to override the theme styles for the tree.  In the case of *your* tree, add the following rule to your global styles.scss file:

```
p-sidebar .p-tree {
    border: none;
}
```

Notice that I have specified the class *.p-tree* and not *.ui-tree*